# Selecting and manipulating mixed nodes

Tags: xpath, simplexml

I have thousands of poorly formatted html documents and I have to fix formatting errors using only php. So far I do well with simplexml and xpath. Now I stumbled over this:

```
<ul>
  Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor sit amet,</strong> consectetur 
  adipiscing elit, <em>sed</em> do eiusmod tempor
  <li>incididunt</li>
  <li>ut</li>
  <li>labo</li>
</ul>
```

Now the Text *Lorem…tempor* belongs outside of the `<ul>` while everything else (*incididunt…labo*) should remain a list item.

So my idea was to select child nodes of `<ul>` that are not `<li>` including text nodes. But can I do this with xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can union two xpathes. The first finds all not li nodes, the second - text nodes under ul

```
//ul/*[name() != "li"] | //ul/text()
```

Comment: Thank you, it did precisely what I needed.